# ul CSS Layout Issue with Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I use bootstrap responsive layout and I have an unordered list looks fine in Firefox, Opera, IE except Chrome browser (version 28). In Chrome it looks like this in the picture: [image]

Here is the CSS Styling:

```
ul {
   margin: 20px;

   li {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;

      div {                             // the icon
          color: #0085AF;
          display: inline-block;
          font-size: 12px;
          width: 10%;
      }

      p {                               // the text
         display: inline-block;
         float: right;
         margin-bottom: 0;
         width: 89%;

         a {
          font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
          margin-left: 10px;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The reset styling for ul li is:

```
ul, li {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       border: 0;
       font-size: 100%;
       font: inherit;
       vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

I couldn't figure out which setting I should change without breaking the current layout, the text should line up with the icon, and above the border line, not sitting on it! why it's doing this?

Comment: **Please also provide the HTML you use for this example.**

Comment: Yes, I care. I was just testing it out. Thank you very much, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

use `display: block;`  rather than `display: inline-block;`